# Post bitmap to a specific album with Facebook sdk android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

i have a problem.

I have to load an image in the album "mobile uploads" , but i can't figure out how to specify the album .

This is my code

```
    public void sharePhoto(Bitmap bitmap){
        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bitmap)
                .setCaption("Title")
                .build();

        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        ShareApi.share(content, null);
 }
```

These are the permissions I've given to the app:

```
permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions user_photos");
```

I read that I should use the GraphRequest , but can not figure out how to get the specific id of the album " Mobile uploads " and then how to use it to post the bitmap .

Here's the code :

```
new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "album-id",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.w("LOG: ", response.toString());
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I would try this first on the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me) to better understand the calls needed. (e.g. `GET /me/albums` then get the album id). But in all cases, I think making a `POST /me/photos` call will put the image in the mobile uploads anyway.